# HLS segment (.ts) internal format

Tags: video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

I try to understand how HLS segmenter converts MPEG-TS packets into HLS chunks. Does HLS chunk incapsulates several MPEG-TS packets, or it's a completely different format and differs from MPEG-TS? For example, can I retrieve PCR (Program Clock Reference) or other MPEG-TS specific data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#page-5):

> Each Media Segment MUST be formatted as an MPEG-2 Transport Stream
> [ISO_13818], a WebVTT [WebVTT] file, or a Packed Audio file ...

In other words: `HLS` is built on top of `MPEG-TS`. Video is always formatted as an MPEG Transport Stream. Subtitles use `WebVTT`. Audio can formatted either as an `MPEG-TS` or raw `AAC`/`MP3` frames.

When video/audio is formatted as `MPEG-TS`, each HLS segment is self contained (i.e. contains all necessary decoding information) and consists of many MPEG-TS packets (an MPEG-TS packet is just 188 bytes).

Yes, you can retrieve PCR and everything else that's embedded in the MPEG-TS, for instance ID3 metadata, other multiplexed streams, [CEA 608/708](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEA-708) and so on.

The next version of HLS will [allow fragmented MP4](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/) to be used as an alternative to `MPEG-TS` for video/audio but at the moment support is limited.